# WindowManager$BadTokenException unable to add window

Tags: android, android-camera, android-windowmanager

I am developing app for **background videorecording** ,thats why i used WindowManager,but it did not worked for me.gives following errors:

```
08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.prankapp.BackgroundVideoRecorder: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@418c0b68 -- permission denied for this window type
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2277)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1215)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@418c0b68 -- permission denied for this window type
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:707)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at com.example.prankapp.BackgroundVideoRecorder.onCreate(BackgroundVideoRecorder.java:53)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200):     ... 10 more
```

My windowManager code:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(BackgroundVideoRecorder.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            );
            //layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
            surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
08-23 15:38:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(4200): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@418c0b68 -- permission denied for this window type
```

**Problem:**
 Permission missing in maifest file.

**Solution:**
Use following permission in `AndroidManifest`.

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Comment: one activity,one service & following permissions **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission>**

Comment: Try android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW instead of android:name="SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

Comment: @MBH, maybe add permissions during runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t

Comment: yup permissions has to be handled at runtime for marshmallow. This answer was posted for pre-marshmallow. Will update my answer in sometime.

Comment: With marshmallo this issue persists. So to avoid please see the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521

Comment: here is the latest working answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208897/android-permission-denied-for-window-type-2038-using-type-application-overlay

Answer (score 10):

if your application `apiLevel >= 19`, don't use

WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

you can use

`LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST`

or

`TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL`

now my code for LayoutParams is like,

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: for Lollipop and lower I used WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, but It didn't work for Android M, then I used WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST as you suggested and it works now, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `TYPE_TOAST` works when you are not using to draw on lockscreen

Comment: I have to use `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` ?

Comment: t0m: if you use the TYPE_TOAST, no permission needed

Comment: `LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` is deprecated from API 26. Use `LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead and it is requires `android.Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission => [See more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_TOAST)

Comment: I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?` when using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` instead of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` on Pixel emulator API 25, though it works ok for Android 23 emulator, weird...

Answer (score 0):

Starting from marshmallow versions  the permission approval is a little bit complex. So even after giving the above permission this issue is not resolved. Please see the following link.

[Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@44da9bc0 -- permission denied for this window type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521)