# Unable to start a dialog in my class that extends GcmListenerService

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

Am trying to create a dialog when i receive a certain type of message in my class which extends `GcmListenerService`

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    final String senderName = data.getString("sender");
    final String message = data.getString("message");

    if(senderName != null && senderName.equals("XXX")){
       final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setTitle("Alert!")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        try {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                    alertDialog.show();
                    Looper.loop();

                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**but am getting an exception** `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

**at this line** `final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();`

**My Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainActivityBar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //other statements and methods here
}
```

**My manifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/mainActivityTheme">
    </activity>
```

**My style resource**

```
<style name="mainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

**Where am i doing it the wrong way?**

Comment: Why are you trying to use AppCompatActivity (which is used for activities with an action bar) when you have a NoActionBar theme?

Comment: @TimCastelijns  because i need to `setSupportActionBar` and i can't do it by extending Activity

Comment: @TimCastelijns   or is there way i can `setSupportActionBar` without extending `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Normally, when you want to use the action bar, you use a theme other than NoActionBar, looking at the name, the reason should be obvious

Answer (score 0):

I had to extend `AppCompatActivity` in my activity because i wanted to use `setSupportActionBar()` method to set **my toolbar as the actionbar**.

To solve the problem, i did some changes in my class that extends `GcmListenerService`

i changed

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.mainActivityTheme));
```

**This is my class that extends gcmlistener service**

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
final String senderName = data.getString("sender");
final String message = data.getString("message");

if(senderName != null && senderName.equals("XXX")){
   final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.mainActivityTheme));

    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle("Alert!")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    try {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                alertDialog.show();
                Looper.loop();

            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`
**my style used by my activity and my AlertDialog.Builder**

```
<style name="mainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Getting the following error: "Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2728b31 -- permission denied for this window type" any suggestions?

Comment: Ah got it: Cool! Worked for me... Needed to add:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />  as noted by this dude:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400539/windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window

Comment: @MoeHoward      well i was far away, but when i returned, i have found that you solved the problem. great.  if this answer helped you, don't forget to upvote it :)