# Do i need android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW for WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have seen: `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` always in combination with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482868/4244605).

Consider this code:

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            100, 100,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
```

Do i need for this code `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permissions?

From [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) about `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`:

> Allows an app to create windows using the type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other apps. Very few apps should use this permission; these windows are intended for system-level interaction with the user.

It's about `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` not about `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`. Hm?

**UPDATE:**
line: `windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@10dca8ac -- permission denied for this window type
```

So probably `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` is necessary.

Comment: I recommend you post your solution as answer, and accept it, my first impression once I saw your question is that it is not answered yet, but your second update helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change
`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST`.
`android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` removed from Apps settings and it works.

Inspired: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113007/4244605)

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            100, 100,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
```

It seems that this solution do not need `android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"`

**UPDATE**
`LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` is deprecated from API 26. Use `LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` instead and it is requires `android.Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission => [See more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_TOAST)

Comment: :D you have to ask permission anyway

Comment: I get `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?` when using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST` instead of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` on Pixel emulator API 25, though it works ok for Android 23 emulator, weird...