# TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY permission denied 2038 on Android N?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-windowmanager

I need to draw a system overlay view from a service. This is the part that adds this view to WindowManager:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

It failed with permission denied exception:

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f15e8de -- permission denied for window type 2038
```

I have tried everything I found online and still not able to get this permission to pass.

- I have SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in manifest.
- I have to use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY and not any other TYPE.
- I checked `Settings.canDrawOverlays` and it is true.
- I checked my app has `Draw over other apps` permission enabled in App Settings.

I looked at all the answers in [Android: permission denied for window type 2038 using TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208897/android-permission-denied-for-window-type-2038-using-type-application-overlay) but none of them solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing this error on some devices, most of them are Vivo android 8.0. Have you already had the solution for this one? Plz let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should choose another type for Android N:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
}

WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        flags,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: How can I restrict it . https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215