# Unable to add window Exception

Tags: android, sdk, android-windowmanager

I have this error in just android 5.1

```
 Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1df76e3 -- the specified window type is not valid
```

this is the code :

```
wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
...
 wm.addView(relativeLayout, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this permission in AndroidManifest.

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

on API >= 23 [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521)

Comment: I think you forgot the link - and looks like you copy/pasted the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7570071/3847