# Marshmallow permission implementation

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-runtime

I am trying to add Android 6.0 support in my Existing Android App. I have used `SYNCADAPTER` to sync data. its working fine till API 22. but in 23 (ANDROID 6.0) they have remove Group permission `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`.

I found sample [how to get run-time permission](https://github.com/googlesamples/), I tried same with `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` but it is not working.

I also found one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065680/1168654), Is there any trick to use `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` same as that answer?

i found removed permissions list [overhere](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/17/random-musings-android-6p0-sdk.html). so if my app use that permission which is listed. in that case does any app works in Android M (6.0)?

Comment: "they have remove Group permission AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" -- what specific portions of the Android SDK were you using that required `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`? Check the current JavaDocs, as you may not need that permission on API Level 23.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i have used SyncAdapter to get data from backend that's why i need that permission. i am not facing any issue my app is running perfectly on 6.0. but i am trying to implement permission model for 6.0. so is it not necessary to get AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS permission from user in 6.0 ?

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no longer need AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS on Android 6.0.

you can use **`android:maxSdkVersion="22"`** on your **uses-permission** element to stop requesting it as of Android 6.0.

As mentioned in comment by CommonsWare Sir and [this blog](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) helped to understand more on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS this permission no exist any more, as google project manager said.

[Issue 2592:   Requesting AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS permission prompts to: 'Allow app to perform an unknown action'](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2592)

> We'll have to wait for a future preview revision to pursue this because  the M revision 2 'key changes'
>   section states: "Some accounts and identity permissions are moved to
>   CONTACTS permissions group and others are removed or granted based on
>   account type. In particular, android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS,
>   android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS, and
>   android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS are ungrouped pending further
>   changes in a later release."
>   http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html