# Android M Permissions: Missing some of the old ones

Tags: android

I have to implement the new permissions system but i cant find some of the permissions i used earlier in my android apss:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

For example: I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I can now replace this by

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.CONTACTS" />
```

Because `GET_ACCOUNTS` is in the Group of `CONTACTS`.
But what about the other permissions i posted. They are not listed anywhere in the [system permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following permissions are not present in Android M.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Hence, you can request them using `android:maxSdkVersion="22"` in you `uses-permission` tag like this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601456/marshmallow-permissions).

As for the last permission. That is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

You don't need to use the permission request for it, as it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some permissions got deprecated in API level 23. If you are targeting API 23, then take care appropriately (i.e. request permission in runtime for "dangerous" permissions).

I think you should still keep them in manifest file for older SDKs.