# Android permissions removed in API level 23

Tags: android, permissions

In my project I have two permissions:

> android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
>
> android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS

that was removed in API Level 23 https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.Manifest.permission

Does that mean I can remove them if my **targetSdkVersion** is 23 or higher or **minSdkVersion** must be 23?

Answer (score 1):

No you need to add [`android:maxSdkVersion="22"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element#maxSdk) to these both permissions. Like below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

---

[Everything every Android Developer must know about new Android's Runtime Permission](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) is a very good article for more info. And found [Android M Permissions: Missing some of the old ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507601/android-m-permissions-missing-some-of-the-old-ones) similar to your issue.

Comment: Why? Let's say my targetSdkVersion is 23 but I also support older devices so  minSdkVersion is 16 do I need them?

Comment: @Giks91 Yes. It will say framework that if your application is running on 23 or later, do not ask these permissions. But if application is running below 23 allow these permission (in default way)