# Application not installed error Developing Android app

Tags: android, manifest, android-debug, android-debugging

I developed an app recently and send it to a shop in our country called CafeBazaar to put it for sale but in an email they said:

> we installed this app on Huawei P8lite with android 6.0 and we got
>   this error "Application not installed"

Now I searched a lot about this kind of error but this is very general error in my opinion and I can't determine how should solve this error

My manifest is like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>

 <meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
 <application
    android:name="com.android.example.example.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

I searched a lot but usually answer was put this two below attribute in your application tag on manifest:

- `android:debuggable="true"`
- `android:testOnly="false"`

I didn't done this yet but I want to know what should I do?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio try first to clean your project. If you are trying to install the apk in a real device and you has installed one time at least, try to clear the cache from this apk (you can do that in settings -> apps -> yourApp in your device) and uninstall it manually

Comment: Hi Thanks for response
I made an signed-apk version and gave them this version but they got this error

Comment: which is your minimum android version code your this apk? ( `minSdkVersion` )

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo 
compileSdkVersion 28-
minSdkVersion 21-
targetSdkVersion 28-
versionCode 2-
versionName "1.2"-

Comment: try reading this issue with the `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` for android 6.0

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601456/marshmallow-permission-implementation

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo So you are saying that if i remove this permission it can solve problem?

Comment: Maybe, as said in this post: `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS this permission no exist any more, as google project manager said`. This could be producing that error. I would try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several weeks of headache i finally find solution and i put it here so if anyone had same problem can solve it.

For this problem i putted this two attribute in application tag:

- android:debuggable="false"
- android:testOnly="false"

and finally it solved my problem.

```
<application
    android:name="com.android.example.example.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:testOnly="false" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was signing my app with both the signatures **v1** and **v2**

[image]

You could try selecting one if you signed with both methods.

Comment: thanks for reply i signed my apk  just with V1 because some where in StackOverFlow i read that signing with both can cause problem in some phones !!?? is that true ?

Comment: Yes, it is true.