# Upgrading to Android SDK to Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've recently discovered that Android M locks down the option to automatically allow users to draw over other apps, which is outlined in this article 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/07/android-m-begins-locking-down-floating-apps-requires-users-to-grant-special-permission-to-draw-on-other-apps/

So I've tried to upgrade my API to 23 to account for this change. As outlined in this post
[Permission from manifest doesn't work in Android 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061934/permission-from-manifest-doesnt-work-in-android-6).
However, the Settings.canDrawOverlay() and others don't seem to appear in my Android SDK. I was wondering if I missed anything in upgrading my SDK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 in your module's `build.gradle` file. Or, if you are using Eclipse, set your Build Target to android-23.