# Draw over Other Apps Issue | switch is grayed out

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

[Permission from manifest doesn't work in Android 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061934/permission-from-manifest-doesnt-work-in-android-6)
I followed this above post which I made work and bring up the intent prompt for my app to draw over others. Sadly I am finding that the **switch is grayed out**. After some googling

I have seen that others have pointed towards screen filter services that are the culprit, except I do not have any of those installed. Also, I have seen that other apps (i.e. `Facebook Messenger`) are not grayed out and I can switch the `permission` on and off with no issues.

Am I missing something in my code to cause they `permission` switch to be grayed out?

EDIT:
I found another post with nearly an identical issue using the same device running the same version of Android.
[Android "Screen Overlay Detected" message if user is trying to grant a permission when a notification is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453759/android-screen-overlay-detected-message-if-user-is-trying-to-grant-a-permissio?rq=1)

tested in device `Moto` and `Nexus 6P`

More Edit:
Also tested on `Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge` and `AVD` running `SDK 23` with the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple error. I had in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

when it should have been

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```