# Draw on top of screen without permission request above 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to know how to draw something on top on screen without permission request.

I had implement an app can draw something on the top on screen by [this post](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/), it worked fine before my device version update to 6.0.

When my app run on devices above 6.0, I met a permission issue that I need to ask user to request SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in app as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061934/permission-from-manifest-doesnt-work-in-android-6) says, and it worked fine when I implement the permission request code.

But I found many apps can draw many things on top of screen without this permission on google play store, like [Draw on screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.makeez.drawonscreen), [Screen Draw Screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kewitschka.screendrawlite), etc.

How can I implement this function with permission like these apps?

Can someone help me?

Comment: I see both apps uses: **draw over other apps** permission.

Comment: just set target sdk version to 22 and you can do it without asking permission

Comment: @Morshues please mark the answer if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set `target sdk version = 22` and you can do it without asking permission.

Btw it is not a good practice you should absolutely use the new Runtime `Permission` of 6.0

Comment: Thank you. It's work and really interesting, so if minSdkVersion over 6.0 in the future, those apps will meet the same issue right?

Comment: no as soon as you set target to 6.0 or above u have to use the new runtime permission model