# How to listen ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION is allowed

Tags: java, android

I use following code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 5469);
```

to get SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, how to run code after this permission is allowed

Comment: take look at this guy answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33503523/488434, onActivityResult should let you know by checking against `Settings.canDrawOverlays` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use this requestPermissions

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_SDCARD);
```

Then use this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {


        }
    }
```

When use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 5469);
```

Then use this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==5469)
    {


    }
}
```