# Settings.canDrawOverlays is returning false even after turning the permission on from settings

Tags: android, overlay, system-alert-window

I am trying billow Code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283823/4542608) answer to check if the permission is enabled. but it is returning false even when the permission is enabled from the settings.

```
public static boolean canDrawOverlayViews(Context con){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){return true;}
    try {
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(con);
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
        return canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(con);
    }
}


public static boolean canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(Context context) {

    try {

        AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        Class clazz = AppOpsManager.class;
        Method dispatchMethod = clazz.getMethod("checkOp", new Class[] { int.class, int.class, String.class });
        //AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW = 24
        int mode = (Integer) dispatchMethod.invoke(manager, new Object[] { 24, Binder.getCallingUid(), context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() });

        return AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == mode;

    } catch (Exception e) {  return false;  }

}
```

Comment: This Answer will may help you out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652533/android-system-overlay-window...

Comment: Could you solve that? I have the same issue in on of my apps...

Comment: This always returns false for me. Tested on Android 8.1 , Pixel 2.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I've also faced the same issue and got the following workaround . 
Referenced from 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198671#c7

```
public boolean getWindoOverLayAddedOrNot2() {

   String sClassName = "android.provider.Settings";
   try {
       Class classToInvestigate = Class.forName(sClassName);
       if (context == null)
           context = activity;
       Method method = classToInvestigate.getDeclaredMethod("isCallingPackageAllowedToDrawOverlays", Context.class, int.class, String.class, boolean.class);
       Object value = method.invoke(null, context, Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName(), false);

       Log.i("Tag", value.toString());
       // Dynamically do stuff with this class
       // List constructors, fields, methods, etc.

   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // Class not found!
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // Unknown exception
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: It returns false for me, always. Tested on Android 8.1 on Pixel 2.

Answer (score 0):

does the check involves the device admin?
I have encountered this problem when disabling device admin, I have checked this permission in the DeviceAdminReceiver->onDisabled() and on some devices, and canDrawOverlays returned false, despite the fact i had the permission.

The above answer helped sometimes but not all the time. the thing that did work is Thread.sleep before the check.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(20);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // some exception here
}
```

The minimal time that worked for me was 20 millis. than canDrawOverlays returned true

Note: this is not a good practice however this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on [BennyP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42134910/4721397)'s answer, I've made a Runnable run the required code after 500ms and that worked very well. The feedback is a bit delayed, but the user won't even notice the delay.

This is the code I've added to my `onResume()`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!Settings.canDrawOverlays(ControllerActivity.this)){
                //Handle overlay permission not given here
            }
            else{
                //Handle overlay permission given here
            }
        }
    }, 500);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried restarting the activity after the user accessed the setting . This is code :

public static void restartActivity(Activity act){

Intent intent = getIntent();

finish();

startActivity(intent);

}

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am really very surprised with this strange behaviour of

```
    Settings.canDrawOverlays(this);
```

I also faced the same issue with its usage, it was returning false even if the permission is already assigned.
What I noticed that, I was using this check in my onStart() method, where it was creating this wired behavior. To resolve this, I searched over internet and no result was there that can satisfy me and the one I can use.

### Solution

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       
        Log.e("Overlay Permission", "" + Settings.canDrawOverlays(this));
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            MyPreferences.saveBoolean(HomeScreen.this, "showOverlayPermissionDialog", true);
        } else {
            MyPreferences.saveBoolean(HomeScreen.this, "showOverlayPermissionDialog", false);
        }
    }
```

I did something lake this, in my onCreate(). Here I saved the values accordingly in my SharedPreferences, and according to these Shared Preference values, I created a check for showing an overlay dialog in my onStart(). This worked fine!

You can try this solution, and mark this answer useful if your problem is solved.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot simply flip the return value, the problem is it canDrawOverlay always returns false right after. With this code you would always assume that the user granted this permission