# Error when I try to start the service from main Activity

Tags: android

I have an Android app that in the main class start a service. So I have this error

```
06-09 09:34:00.880 26760-26760/it.eresult.decipher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service it.eresult.decipher.service.CriticalInformationService@4111f448 with Intent { cmp=it.eresult.decipher/.service.CriticalInformationService }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41117e00 -- permission denied for this window type
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2376)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41117e00 -- permission denied for this window type
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:537)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
     at it.eresult.decipher.service.CriticalInformationService.onStartCommand(CriticalInformationService.java:37)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.eresult.decipher">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:background="@color/colorToolBar">


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".service.CriticalInformationService"
            android:label="Critical Information Service"
            >
        </service>

        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

With this code, I try to start the service:

```
startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));
```

Then, this is the Service:

```
public class CriticalInformationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO do something useful
        WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_activity, null);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
/* | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON */,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

> EDIT

This is the MainActivity that launch Service

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        checkPremission();
        //startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));
    }

    void checkPremission() {
        //select which permission you want
        final String permission = Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW;
        // if in fragment use getActivity()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LoginActivity.this, permission)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        } else {
            // you have permission go ahead launch service

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                        && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                if (isGranted) {
                    // you have permission go ahead launch service
                }else{
                    // you dont have permission show toast
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521 probably help

Comment: I have read that post, but I don't understand how can I fixed my error

Comment: have asked this `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`permission at runtime in API 23

Comment: ok, then?? How can change my code?

Comment: @bircastri launch service after getting permissions in api 23 see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        checkPremission();
        //startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));
    }

    void checkPremission() {
        //select which permission you want
        final String permission = Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW;
        // if in fragment use getActivity()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LoginActivity.this, permission)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
            }
        } else {
            // you have permission go ahead launch service
            startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                        && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                if (isGranted) {
                    // you have permission go ahead launch service
                    startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));
                }else{
                    // you dont have permission show toast
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I copy and paste, this code on my MinActivity right?

Comment: where you are calling this `startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class));` now call this `checkPremission()`

Comment: I have edit my first post and I have add a MainActivity. With this code, I have the some error

Comment: thanks for your reply and post, but in checkPermission I can't execute startService(new Intent(this, CriticalInformationService.class), I should change the code on Mainfest file ???