# Error Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e46c220 -- permission denied for window type 2010

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Hello when running my lock screen application it crash after the lock screen show up this is the expection that show up:

```
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e46c220 -- permission denied for window type 2010
```

Here my full logcat errors log:

```
    07-23 20:09:26.029 24670-24783/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
07-23 20:09:27.581 24670-24822/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:27.582 24670-24822/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:27.595 24670-24821/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:27.596 24670-24821/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:27.892 24670-24849/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:27.894 24670-24849/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:28.564 24670-24836/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:28.566 24670-24836/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:28.669 24670-24836/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
07-23 20:09:28.777 24670-24818/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:28.778 24670-24818/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:29.031 24670-24874/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:29.034 24670-24874/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:31.910 24670-24874/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(289)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
07-23 20:09:32.179 24670-24909/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:32.183 24670-24909/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:32.266 24670-24670/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.konkas.lockingscreenings, PID: 24670
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.konkas.lockingscreenings/com.konkas.lockingscreenings.activity.LockNoPasscode}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e46c220 -- permission denied for window type 2010
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e46c220 -- permission denied for window type 2010
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at com.konkas.lockingscreenings.activity.LockNoPasscode.mWindowAddView(LockNoPasscode.java:341)
        at com.konkas.lockingscreenings.activity.LockNoPasscode.onCreate(LockNoPasscode.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
07-23 20:09:32.555 24670-24914/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:32.556 24670-24914/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
07-23 20:09:32.582 24670-24916/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
  07-23 20:09:32.584 24670-24916/com.konkas.lockingscreenings E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 
    15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)
```

What can I do to resolve this errors and crashes,I also tried already add

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

But it didn't help and I still keep getting the same errors..
What should I do to resolve this errors and crashes,which files do I need to edit and what code do I need to change in them,much apperiacte for any help and support thanks at advance!

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982167/android-permission-denied-for-window-type-2010-in-marshmallow-or-higher) SO question?

Comment: But I can't understand where should exactly I copy this code...I got already an java code that needs to get this added but where do I add it,in the start in the middle?How do I manage to do that without getting errors from android studio about not importing the code in the right place?
@JeroenHeier

Comment: I tried to do that,but it dosen't help at all,does someone else got some idea on how to resolve my issues?