# Unable to add window -- the specified window type is not valid

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

I keep receiving this exception, when i try to create a system wide overlay using a WindowManager and the corresponding permission:

```
 Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@6b3c898 -- the specified window type is not valid
```

My Code (run from my activities onCreate):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                /** if not construct intent to request permission */
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                /** request permission via start activity for result */
                startActivityForResult(intent, CHECK_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            );
            View overlay = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.overlay_playback_controls, null);
            //overlay.setOnClickListener(this);

            windowManager.addView(overlay, layoutParams);
        }
```

And if needed, heres the corresponding xml-layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test!!!"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already tried all hints from this post (including the linked one), but still have no idea what the problem is: [Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@44da9bc0 -- permission denied for this window type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521)

Comment: Strange. With only a slight modification (adding a final static int CHECK_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) I was able to get this to execute with no issue.  What version of Android and/or which device/emulator are you using to test this on? Also, what sdk version are you targeting and compiling against?

Comment: Even more interesting, that you managed to make it run. I simply forgot the constant int when copying the code. But I was able to make it run. I was focusing on permissions because i read that this error is produced by that, but i simply forgot to introduce a "height" for the layoutparams, so it wont run because a view without width and height parameters is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

A View without width and height attributes cannot exist, so thats why it didn't run. I simply didn't understand the LayoutParams constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in this way:

```
layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
```

I think `WindowManager.layoutParams` must have a type.

Answer (score 0):

> This Exception was thrown from ViewRootImpl.class

The reason is when you create LayoutParams its must be instance of WindowManager.LayoutParams, and you must set correct flgas.
***Constructor params is not width and height, there are some kind of flags.***
Otherwise you should get this exception.
When Activity object created and then activity create new **PhoneWindow** object which is child class of window.
   PhoneWindow create Window Manager. You can get in by calling **getWindowManager()** from actvity.

Root view was created by WindowManager;

***line 599***

```
  case WindowManagerGlobal.ADD_INVALID_TYPE:
                        throw new 
  WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException(
                                "Unable to add window " + mWindow
                                + " -- the specified window type is not 
  valid");
```

> This is an example of that Exception

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.word_detail_activity);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hello");
    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    WindowManager manager = getWindowManager();
    manager.addView(textView,new WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1,-1));
```

> This code is running without Exception

```
    final  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.format =  PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.packageName = getPackageName();

    WindowManager manager = getWindowManager();
    manager.addView(textView, params);
```