# interact_across_users_full permission not granted android

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I'm trying to create an overlay window to record tapping in my service, but I cannot start the app. I followed this link: [Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@44da9bc0 -- permission denied for this window type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t).

Basically I asked permission from the phone:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
```

However my phone tells me: Permission Denial: `getCurrentUser() from pid=10296, uid=5010 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS`

I searched around for this error and added `"permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"`" to my manifest, but I'm getting the following message and the app still doesn't run:

W/PackageManager: Package com.example.ashoklab2016.project1 attempting to redeclare system permission android.permission.`INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`; ignoring new declaration

May I get some suggestions about where I should preceed? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot hold `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`, unless your app is part of the firmware, and you cannot redefine `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` yourself to try to trick Android into allowing you to hold that permission. "May I get some suggestions about where I should preceed?" -- you might provide a [mcve] of the code that is triggering the exception, along with the full stack trace for the exception.