# Include an React-Nativ View into an existing Android App

Tags: android, react-native

I have a very simple Android-App, with one view that has a button to an other view. 
In that other view i have to show an React-Native component. I followed the instructions on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#integration-with-existing-apps my Activity is this my tiny code:

```
public class MyReactActivity extends Activity {

private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("main.jsbundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android.js")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactApp", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

This app starts ok ,but when i touched the button to change the view, the app crashes with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.kris.testa, PID: 2612
              android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@65e68b3 -- permission denied for window type 2003
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:703)
                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
                  at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.handleReloadJS(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:538)
                  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$3$1.run(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:386)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kris.testa">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyReactActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try using this permission in AndroidManifest.
>
> `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`
>
> **[on API >= 23 see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521)**

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7570071/1796309

If you're using Android version >= 6.0, then you have to follow Android Permission model, i.e. you have to request this permission in runtime.

If you don't want to request permission in runtime, just set your `targetSdkVersion` to `22` in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.goenglish.goenglish"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22          <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: hm, I already have: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />, I'll add this into the post.

Comment: Ah, Thanks a lot. i'll give it a try.