# Android 4.2 ACTION_OUTSIDE MotionEvent X and Y return 0 outside of own application

Tags: android, window, touch

I created a `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` view, set the flags `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` and `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`, and added it with `WindowManager.addView()`.

When I touch outside of the view onto my own activity, everything works and `MotionEvent.getY()` returns the correct value.

However, if I exit my activity and and touch onto another application, `MotionEvent.getY()` always returns 0.

I'm not sure if this only happens on 4.2 or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's unfortunate that this question has remained unanswered for 1.5 years, but I ran into the same thing you did and found out why!

After scouring the source code, I found the source of the issue:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/79e0206ef3203a1842949242e58fa8f3c25eb129/services/input/InputDispatcher.cpp#L1417

```
// Check whether windows listening for outside touches are owned by the same UID. If it is
// set the policy flag that we will not reveal coordinate information to this window.
if (maskedAction == AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN) {
    sp<InputWindowHandle> foregroundWindowHandle =
            mTempTouchState.getFirstForegroundWindowHandle();
    const int32_t foregroundWindowUid = foregroundWindowHandle->getInfo()->ownerUid;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mTempTouchState.windows.size(); i++) {
        const TouchedWindow& touchedWindow = mTempTouchState.windows[i];
        if (touchedWindow.targetFlags & InputTarget::FLAG_DISPATCH_AS_OUTSIDE) {
            sp<InputWindowHandle> inputWindowHandle = touchedWindow.windowHandle;
            if (inputWindowHandle->getInfo()->ownerUid != foregroundWindowUid) {
                mTempTouchState.addOrUpdateWindow(inputWindowHandle,
                        InputTarget::FLAG_ZERO_COORDS, BitSet32(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the "outside touch" lands in a view that doesn't share its UID ([read about it here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/#the-application-sandbox)) with the view that's listening for outside touches, the event dispatcher sets its coordinates to 0,0. This was definitely done for security purposes, but I'm not sure I see the full scope of the threat it's designed to mitigate. And this gentleman [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041604/why-does-action-outside-return-0-everytime-on-kitkat-4-4-2) reports that you can retrieve location data on 2.3.6, but it seems that at least 4.x won't reveal it to you (I tried 4.1.2, it didn't work).

I opened up a bug ticket about this if you'd like to follow it. At the very least, the documentation needs to include this information... I would also like to know if this security feature is really necessary.

[Issue 72746:   FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH doesn't return location for ACTION_OUTSIDE events on 4.2+](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72746)

Comment: Not that I've been able to find... If someone has one though, please comment! (Also star the Android bug ticket if you want to receive updates - someone may correct the issue eventually.)

Comment: still the same as of 2018