# Why does ACTION_OUTSIDE return 0 everytime on KitKat 4.4.2?

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener, motion, motionevent

I have implemented a window with size 1 and want to catch `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event.

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,1,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I get the trigger and I get the `ACTION_OUTSIDE` event, but when reading `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()` they both return 0 every time.
I tested the same thing with **Android 2.3.6** and it worked. And I can't find anything that is deprecated.

Is it an Android problem or does anyone know a solution?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tniederm, I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076710/android-4-2-action-outside-motionevent-x-and-y-return-0-outside-of-own-applicati?lq=1) for reference, but I'll rehash it here with some minor edits:

After scouring the source code, I found the source of the issue:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/79e0206ef3203a1842949242e58fa8f3c25eb129/services/input/InputDispatcher.cpp#L1417

```
// Check whether windows listening for outside touches are owned by the same UID. If it is
// set the policy flag that we will not reveal coordinate information to this window.
if (maskedAction == AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN) {
    sp<InputWindowHandle> foregroundWindowHandle =
            mTempTouchState.getFirstForegroundWindowHandle();
    const int32_t foregroundWindowUid = foregroundWindowHandle->getInfo()->ownerUid;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mTempTouchState.windows.size(); i++) {
        const TouchedWindow& touchedWindow = mTempTouchState.windows[i];
        if (touchedWindow.targetFlags & InputTarget::FLAG_DISPATCH_AS_OUTSIDE) {
            sp<InputWindowHandle> inputWindowHandle = touchedWindow.windowHandle;
            if (inputWindowHandle->getInfo()->ownerUid != foregroundWindowUid) {
                mTempTouchState.addOrUpdateWindow(inputWindowHandle,
                        InputTarget::FLAG_ZERO_COORDS, BitSet32(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the "outside touch" lands in a view that doesn't share its UID ([read about it here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/#the-application-sandbox)) with the view that's listening for outside touches, the event dispatcher sets its coordinates to 0,0. This was definitely done for security purposes, but I'm not sure I see the full scope of the threat it's designed to mitigate. You can try to look for older versions of the InputDispatcher to find out when exactly this feature was introduced - I haven't looked myself.

I opened up a bug ticket about this if you'd like to follow it. At the very least, the documentation needs to include this information... I would also like to know if this security feature is really necessary.

[Issue 72746:   FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH doesn't return location for ACTION_OUTSIDE events on 4.2+](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72746)

Comment: In my bachelor thesis I developed a keylogger that uses this feature to extract the coordinates. So I see the security issue here. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Oh yeah? Cool! I can see this being used to make a keylogger, but I guess my question is: how useful is the data you obtain from it? Can you tell what other apps the user has installed, where they're located on his Launcher page... basically, how do you know what they're tapping on?

Oh, and if you're satisfied with my answer, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I use the GetTask permission to get the current task. With this information you have a pretty powerful keylogger. Your welcome!

Comment: So Is there any ways to get those Motionevent after 4.2 ??