# Recover every touch event on android from anywhere

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to recover all touch events that occur anywhere on a mobile device (i.e. not only restricted to one activity)

I have a service:

```
public class OverlayExampleService extends Service implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    // window manager
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    // linear layout will use to detect touch event
    private LinearLayout touchLayout;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // create linear layout
        touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // set layout width 30 px and height is equal to full screen
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(30, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // set color if you want layout visible on screen
//  touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        // set on touch listener
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // fetch window manager object
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // set layout parameter of window manager
        WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // width of layout 30 px
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // height is equal to full screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type Phone, These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls).
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, // this window won't ever get key input focus

                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        Log.e(TAG, "add View");

        mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mWindowManager != null) {
            if(touchLayout != null) mWindowManager.removeView(touchLayout);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            Log.e(TAG, "Action :" + event.getAction() + "\t X :" + event.getRawX() + "\t Y :"+ event.getRawY());

        return false;
    }


}
```

And an activity that starts it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent globalService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        globalService = new Intent(this, OverlayExampleService.class);
    }


    public void buttonClicked(View v){

        if(v.getTag() == null){
            startService(globalService);
            v.setTag("on");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            stopService(globalService);
            v.setTag(null);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the activity's layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start Touch Detection"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works, and I can successfully recover Touch X/Y locations but once that is done the touch event is consumed. **I would like it to continue onto the activity/display in the backgorund** (i.e. Home screen, other apps etc.).

I have tried returning false in the onTouch function but that does not seem to work.

I also know about this issue: [Android 4.2 ACTION_OUTSIDE MotionEvent X and Y return 0 outside of own application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076710/android-4-2-action-outside-motionevent-x-and-y-return-0-outside-of-own-application) and that is why I have my windowManger parameters spanning the whole screen (MATCH_PARENT parameters).

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No, the Android framework does not allow an app to observe touch events without consuming them.

Comment: Even when returning false from the onTouch function?

Comment: Correct. Once a window receives a touch event, only that window will receive the event.