# click and draggable drawer in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need a help for developing clickable and draggable drawer functionality from bottom to top in angular js directive. How to do that ? I have come up with clickable functionality somehow but i just want to know how to do it in a draggable way. Could any one help me / show me the code ? It would be much helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: see [this stackoverflow questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768360/draggable-drawer-with-a-handle-instead-of-action-bar-on-top-of-other-apps)

Comment: @Beartums Not useful and it's for android i believe.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry about that.  Your probably should have downvoted me (but thanks for not doing so).