# Detect Swipe Gesture in WindowManager

Tags: android, swipe-gesture, android-windowmanager

> I know how to achieve Swipe Gesture on Views.

But I want to get **SwipeGesture in WindowManager** like this [**app doing**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures)

As far as I know `Gesture detector works on view`. I have tried to detect `Gesture` but don't know how to achieve it. Can someOne shed some light on how to achieve.

**What I think is:**

There must be a `Transparent View` to detect Swipe in this app Or is there an other way round.

**Edit**

I know how to add an `Overlay window`. And add a `view` to it. And then add `GestureListener` to it. **What my Question is** , Is it possible to add a `gesture Listener to WindowManager` without having a view. And how it can be achieved . Any sample code or example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one detect screen gestures outside ones own app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910982/how-can-one-detect-screen-gestures-outside-ones-own-app)

Comment: actually, in reference app , that view is not transparent. It's shown as blurred view in top or bottom.